# Hibernate/MySQL join tables based on unique key

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hql

I'm working with hibernate 4.3.11.Final and MySql 5.6.

I'm trying to understand the following behavior:

**Tables:**

```
create table table_a (
    id integer not null auto_increment,
    code_table_a varchar(12) not null,
    desc_table_a varchar(50) not null,
    primary key (id),
    constraint ux_code_table_a unique (code_table_a)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

create table table_b (
    id integer not null auto_increment,
    code_table_b varchar(12) not null,
    desc_table_b varchar(50) not null,
    code_table_a varchar(12) not null,
    primary key (id),
    constraint ux_code_table_b unique (code_table_b),
    constraint ix_table_b_code_table_a_fk foreign key (code_table_a) references table_a (code_table_a)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Please, note that the foreign key on table_b references a unique key in table_a (not the primary key).**

**Mappings:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_a")
public class TableA implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8419151902341044850L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "code_table_a")
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "desc_table_a")
    private String description;

    // hashCode and equals are based on the "code" property only

    // getters / setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "table_b")
public class TableB implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 943565980437511902L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "code_table_b")
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "desc_table_b")
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "code_table_a", referencedColumnName = "code_table_a", unique = true)
    private TableA tableA;

    // hashCode and equals are based on the "code" property only

    // getters / setters
}
```

**HQL 1:**

```
public List<TableB> findByCodeTableA(String codeTableA) {
    StringBuilder select = new StringBuilder("select tableB from TableB tableB ");
    select.append("where tableB.tableA.code = :codeTableA ");
    // select.append("inner join tableB.tableA tableA ");
    // select.append("where tableA.code = :codeTableA ");

    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    Query query = session.createQuery(select.toString());
    query.setParameter("codeTableA", codeTableA);

    List<TableB> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    lista.addAll(query.list());

    return lista;
}
```

**Log for HQL 1:**

```
21 Jan 2016 09:33:17,505 DEBUG SQL - 
    /* select
        tableB 
    from
        TableB tableB 
    where
        tableB.tableA.code = :codeTableA  */ select
            tableb0_.id as id1_1_,
            tableb0_.code_table_b as code_tab2_1_,
            tableb0_.desc_table_b as desc_tab3_1_,
            tableb0_.code_table_a as code_tab4_1_ 
        from
            table_b tableb0_ cross 
        join
            table_a tablea1_ 
        where
            tableb0_.code_table_a=tablea1_.code_table_a 
            and tablea1_.code_table_a=?
21 Jan 2016 09:33:17,560 DEBUG SQL - 
    /* load com.baldotech.hibernatepg.model.TableA */ select
        tablea0_.id as id1_0_0_,
        tablea0_.code_table_a as code_tab2_0_0_,
        tablea0_.desc_table_a as desc_tab3_0_0_ 
    from
        table_a tablea0_ 
    where
        tablea0_.code_table_a=?
21 Jan 2016 09:33:17,577 DEBUG SQL - 
    /* load com.baldotech.hibernatepg.model.TableA */ select
        tablea0_.id as id1_0_0_,
        tablea0_.code_table_a as code_tab2_0_0_,
        tablea0_.desc_table_a as desc_tab3_0_0_ 
    from
        table_a tablea0_ 
    where
        tablea0_.code_table_a=?
```

**HQL 2:**

```
public List<TableB> findByCodeTableA(String codeTableA) {
    StringBuilder select = new StringBuilder("select tableB from TableB tableB ");
    // select.append("where tableB.tableA.code = :codeTableA ");
    select.append("inner join tableB.tableA tableA ");
    select.append("where tableA.code = :codeTableA ");

    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    Query query = session.createQuery(select.toString());
    query.setParameter("codeTableA", codeTableA);

    List<TableB> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    lista.addAll(query.list());

    return lista;
}
```

**Log Output for HQL 2:**

```
21 Jan 2016 09:32:17,733 DEBUG SQL - 
    /* select
        tableB 
    from
        TableB tableB 
    inner join
        tableB.tableA tableA 
    where
        tableA.code = :codeTableA  */ select
            tableb0_.id as id1_1_,
            tableb0_.code_table_b as code_tab2_1_,
            tableb0_.desc_table_b as desc_tab3_1_,
            tableb0_.code_table_a as code_tab4_1_ 
        from
            table_b tableb0_ 
        inner join
            table_a tablea1_ 
                on tableb0_.code_table_a=tablea1_.code_table_a 
        where
            tablea1_.code_table_a=?
21 Jan 2016 09:32:17,777 DEBUG SQL - 
    /* load com.baldotech.hibernatepg.model.TableA */ select
        tablea0_.id as id1_0_0_,
        tablea0_.code_table_a as code_tab2_0_0_,
        tablea0_.desc_table_a as desc_tab3_0_0_ 
    from
        table_a tablea0_ 
    where
        tablea0_.code_table_a=?
21 Jan 2016 09:32:17,797 DEBUG SQL - 
    /* load com.baldotech.hibernatepg.model.TableA */ select
        tablea0_.id as id1_0_0_,
        tablea0_.code_table_a as code_tab2_0_0_,
        tablea0_.desc_table_a as desc_tab3_0_0_ 
    from
        table_a tablea0_ 
    where
        tablea0_.code_table_a=?
```

**Question 1:**

As you can see the @ManyToOne association is marked as LAZY:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "code_table_a", referencedColumnName = "code_table_a", unique = true)
private TableA tableA;
```

But the log shows that Hibernate is loading the entity TableA for each entity TableB. Why is that?

**Question 2:**

HQL1 uses implicit join:

```
"where tableB.tableA.code = :codeTableA "
```

HQL2 uses explicit join:

```
"inner join tableB.tableA tableA where tableA.code = :codeTableA "
```

The log shows that hibernate uses a **"CROSS JOIN"** for HQL1 and **"INNER JOIN"** for HQL2.

I do not understand why it uses a cross join on HQL1.

**Question 3:**

If the join is made using the primary key everything works normally: hibernate respects the LAZY association e no CROSS JOIN is used for implicit joins.

So, should I avoid using unique keys as foreign keys?

Why hibernate works differently for each case?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Q1** Hibernate behaves exact as requested.

You are fetching all childs (Table B) of a given parent (Table A) idenitied by the parant key **and** you request to fetch the parent *lazy*.

This leads to

1) join of child to parent (you need join to be able to identify the parent by key), but due to *lazy* strategy you ignore the parent data.

2) In the next step you get the parent data by the key (only one select as the relation is many to one).

My *opinion*, in this case - lazy fething an identifying entity - is contraproductive.